# How do you pass the --mangle-regex option to uglify using gulp-uglify?

Tags: gulp-uglify, uglifyjs2

I'm trying to use the `--mange-regex` option which is documented on UglifyJS2's GItHub README. The problem is, my build uses `gulp-uglify`, and it isn't clearly documented how I should use `--mangle-regex` without the command line.

My goal is to mangle 'private' identifiers (matching `/^_/`)

I've tried:

```
// Gulp setup code left out for brevity (I'm using gulp.src() etc properly)
uglify({
    mangle: {
        toplevel: false
    },
    mangleProperties: {
        regex: /^_/
    }
});
```

and

```
// Gulp setup code left out for brevity (I'm using gulp.src() etc properly)
uglify({
    mangle: {
        regex: /^_/
    }
});
```

Nothing's doin' here. A little help?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the feature is only enabled in the master branch of Uglify as of this writing. The correct syntax, will be:

```
uglify({
    mangleProperties: {
        regex: /^_/
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported but the syntax has changed a little. instead of mangleProperties it's now a 'properties' object inside a 'mangle' object:

Here's my complete code taken from my gulpfile.js, which works as of May 2020:

```
uglify        = require('gulp-uglify');

...

const uglifyOptions = {
    mangle: {
        properties: { regex: /^_/ }
    }
}

...

.pipe( uglify( uglifyOptions ) )
```